# GCP Functions gen2 "You must assign the Invoker role"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-iam

I want to deploy a cloud function that can be called by everyone via http.

This is my deploy script:

```
gcloud functions deploy <MYFUNCTION> --runtime nodejs18 --gen2 --trigger-http --region=europe-west1 --allow-unauthenticated --project=<MYPROJECT> --set-env-vars NODE_ENV=production
```

But I get this warning:

> Warning: You must assign the Invoker role (roles/run.invoker) through
> Cloud Run for 2nd gen functions if you want to allow the function to
> receive requests from additional principals or other given authorities
> in IAM. Note: if you want to achieve the equivalent of assigning the
> Cloud Functions "Admin" or "Developer" role to a 1st gen function, you
> need to assign Cloud Functions "Admin" or "Developer" to the 2nd gen
> function and assign "Cloud Run Invoker" to the Cloud Run service.

**What am I doing wrong?**

***Note**, I am new to GCP and IAM.*

[image: Screenshot of warning]

Comment: It's a warning only, your Cloud Functions should be correctly deployed no?

Comment: Hello @Martin Carlsson, Feel free to update the status of the question.Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: If you enabled the Cloud Pub/Sub service agent on or before April 8, 2021, to support authenticated Pub/Sub push requests, grant the Service Account Token Creator role (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) to the Google-managed service account. Otherwise, this role is granted by default!

Answer (score 3):

As per [Authenticating for invocation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating);

> The user account you are using to access Cloud Functions assigned a
> role that contains the `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` permission.
> By default, the Cloud Functions `Admin` and
> `Developer` roles have this permission.
>
> You need to grant the appropriate invoker role to the calling
> function's service account on the receiving function.
>
> **Cloud Functions (1st gen):** Run the below command for 1st gen
> functions, the invoker role is Cloud Functions Invoker
> (`roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`)
>
> ```
> gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding RECEIVING_FUNCTION \
>   --member='serviceAccount:CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY' \
>   --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
> ```
>
> **Cloud Functions (2nd gen):** Run the below command for 2nd gen functions, the invoker
> role is Cloud Run Invoker (`roles/run.invoker`) and must be granted on
> the underlying service.
>
> ```
> gcloud functions add-invoker-policy-binding RECEIVING_FUNCTION \
>   --member='serviceAccount:CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY'
> ```
>
> where RECEIVING_FUNCTION is the name of the receiving function and
> CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY is the calling function identity, a service
> account email.

Also refer to [IAM Control access on an individual service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access) for more details.

> You can make a service publicly accessible by adding the special
> `allUsers` member type to a service and granting it the
> `roles/run.invoker role`:
>
> ```
> gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding [SERVICE_NAME] \
>     --member="allUsers" \
>     --role="roles/run.invoker"
> ```
>
> Additionally, when you deploy your service with the `gcloud run deploy` command, you can specify whether or
> not to make your service publicly accessible:
>
> ```
> gcloud run deploy [SERVICE_NAME] ... --allow-unauthenticated
> ```